# How to publish product item in google play

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-play, in-app-billing

Hello I have a problem with in-app purchase in my android application. I am just trying to test in-app purchase with test account authorised by a publisher account(note: publisher's merchant account has not verified with bank account yet). I read developer site

http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing.html#billing-testing-test

here, under Setting Up for Test Purchases heading : point 2 says "Make sure that you publish the items (the application can remain unpublished)"

But I am not sure how to publish an Item.

Please help me. sorry for bad English. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the actual matter. An item can be activated or non-activated  state. There is no state like published or unpublished for an item in Inn-app purchase billing configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You can set up an alpha testing application that doesn't get published by clicking Add New Application then choose Alpha Testing to upload your APK file. It won't be published then you can set up in-app purchase items for this application.

Comment: Nop. I just said what is mean by publishing an item.